# Binary rooted tree isomorphism

Tags: algorithms, graphs, reference-request, combinatorics, trees

My trees are rooted and have at most two children at every vertex. I need references that help me solve any or all of the questions below:

- How many isomorphism classes of trees with n vertices are there?
- What are the classical algorithms to decide if two given trees are isomorphic?
- Is there a nice (computable?) isomorphism invariant?

Of course, the answers may depend on the structure used to define the trees, but I guess the correct choice of structure is part of the answer I am seeking.

Comment: Please restrict yourself to only one question per post.

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: Also, what have you tried? Where have you looked?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a classical linear time algorithm for rooted tree isomorphism due to Aho, Hopcroft and Ullman. The algorithm actually uses a simple isomorphism invariant. See for example [lecture notes of Vikram Sharma](http://www.imsc.res.in/~vikram/DiscreteMaths/2011/tree.pdf). Using this, you can solve unrooted tree isomorphism in linear time, as described for example in [Smal's slides](http://logic.pdmi.ras.ru/~smal/files/smal_jass08_slides.pdf). Another classic algorithm is due to [Buss](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~sbuss/ResearchWeb/treeisomorphism/paper.pdf).